# Why am I not getting any output? And there is an InputMismatchException

Tags: java, arrays, exception, stdout, inputmismatchexception

I am trying to solve a practice problem on hackerrank. But, my output is not displaying and the program throws an `InputMismatchException` can someone please help me out?

**Input Format**

- The first line contains and integer `n`, the size of variable `strings`.
- Each of the next `n` lines contains a string `strings[a]` .
- The next line contains `q`, the size of `queries`.
- Each of the next `q` lines contains a string `queries[b]`.

**Output Format**

Return an integer array of the results of all queries in order.

**example input:**

```
4
aba
baba
aba
xzxb
3
aba
xzxb
ab
```

**example output :**

```
2
1
0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------  
/*my program*/

import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    String strings[] = new String[n];
     int count = 0;
    int i,j=0;
    for(int a=0 ; a<n ; a++){
        strings[a] = s.nextLine();
    }

    int q = s.nextInt();
    String queries[] = new String[q];
    for(int b=0; b<q;b++){
        queries[b] = s.nextLine();
    }
    for(i=0; i <= strings.length; i++){

    for(j=0; j <= queries.length; j++){
          if(queries[j].compareTo(strings[i]) == 0){
                count++;
          }          
    }           
    System.out.println(count);
    count = 0;
    }
      }
}

/* 
Output : ~ no response on stdout ~
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Solution.main(Solution.java:22)
*/
```

Comment: What are those `2`, `1` and `0` in your output code snippet?

Comment: Care to read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `s.nextInt()`, it only reads up until the end of the integer, leaving the new line in the buffer.

Therefore when you subsequently call nextLine() it reads in the new line between the `4` and the `aba`.

To work around this, after calling `nextInt()`, call `nextLine()` to move the buffer past the new line.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt();
String strings[] = new String[n];
 int count = 0;
int i,j=0;
s.nextLine();
for(int a=0 ; a<n ; a++){
    strings[a] = s.nextLine();
}
```

and

```
int q = s.nextInt();
String queries[] = new String[q];
s.nextLine();
for(int b=0; b<q;b++){
    queries[b] = s.nextLine();
}
```

**Edit:**

Additionally, in the final for loop, you have put:

`for(j=0; j <= queries.length; j++){`

but this will result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. You actually want:

`for(j=0; j < queries.length; j++){`

**Edit 2:**

The previous edit applies to both for-loops at the end - you want the limit term of the for loop to be `i<strings.length` and `j<queries.length` respectively.

Also, to achieve the expected output, the order of the for-loops should be reversed:

```
for(j=0; j < queries.length; j++){
    int count = 0;
    for(i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (queries[j].compareTo(strings[i] == 0)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.orintln(count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got all the test cases passed. I was wrong about the for loop. Thanks for correcting that hidden error.

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose your `s.nextInt()` in `if(s.hasNextInt()){}`, to be sure that there is effectively an int to read from the Scanner.